# MvcMembership.MVC error "Inheritance security rules violated"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget-package, membership

I installed the following Nuget packages: 
`MvcMembership` and `MvcMembership.MVC` by Troy Goode.

When I run my application I get the following error on my MVC5 application:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MvcMembership.TouchUserOnEachVisitFilter'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

Is this an issue because the security messures for MVC are higher now or that I am missing something else when installing these two packages?

If I comment out 
`GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new TouchUserOnEachVisitFilter());` and go to `http://localhost:64275/MvcMembership/UserAdministration/Index`, I receive this error

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MvcMembership.AuthorizeUnlessOnlyUserAttribute'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

Please let me know what other information I should provide, thank you.

Comment: Is it public or private class?

Comment: @Programmer Both are public from what I am seeing. `public TouchUserOnEachVisitFilter();` and `public AuthorizeUnlessOnlyUserAttribute();`

Comment: Shooting from the hip but try protected sealed instead of public.

Comment: I dug some more and found that maybe an install broke it or you have to add an attribute based on this link; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b8a9274-c7f0-43e2-a3f7-d1ac5016e6d0/systemtypeloadexception-inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I ended up moving onto another package from NuGet, I installed the following on a new Project and migrated what I needed from there (`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples`). I am sure to revisit `MvcMembership.MVC` and the expanded features at a later time.  Thank you for digging deeper.